# Removing old sections of curved line when drawing new sections in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, lines

I have Swift 2 code below that draws curved lines when the user touches and moves their finger across the screen. New sections of the curved line are added as the user moves their finger to give one continuous curved line on screen. (top image)

However, I wish to change the below code so that as each new section of the line is added and drawn to screen, the previous section and earlier sections are deleted, so that all is seen on the screen is the new section and nothing else. (bottom image)

What needs to be modified in the section of code below to achieve this?

[image]

```
// Swift 2 code below tested using Xcode 7.0.1.

class drawLines: UIView {

let path=UIBezierPath()

var previousPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero

var strokeColor:UIColor?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    strokeColor?.setStroke()
    path.lineWidth = 10
    path.stroke()

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
    let currentPoint = touch!.locationInView(self)

    path.moveToPoint(currentPoint)
    previousPoint=currentPoint
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
    let currentPoint = touch!.locationInView(self)
    let midPoint = self.midPoint(previousPoint, p1: currentPoint)

    path.addQuadCurveToPoint(midPoint,controlPoint: previousPoint)
    previousPoint=currentPoint

    self.setNeedsDisplay()

    path.moveToPoint(midPoint)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.touchesEnded(touches!, withEvent: event)
}

func midPoint(p0:CGPoint,p1:CGPoint)->CGPoint
{
    let x=(p0.x+p1.x)/2
    let y=(p0.y+p1.y)/2
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there's no way to remove points from a `UIBezierPath`. The solution you're looking for is to store the points in an array, which you *can* modify freely, then create your path from that point array.

**Update**

I'm getting a bit confused re-reading your post alongside the comments you've posted. That being said, I've tried to make the example below contain all the elements you need – you might have to re-arrange them if I have not understood you 100%.

This code continuously adds points to an array from the point a touch begins, including while it moves. I added a cap to the maximum number of points so that it removes excess line points if needed. When the user releases their finger I've made it clear all the points.

Note: I've tried to keep the code as simple as possible so that it's clear. Once you find the correct combination of adding/removing points that matches your needs, you should probably look at optimising this. In particular, this assumes a naïve method of drawing where all drawing happens simultaneously (vs deltas), which isn't efficient. The method of removing excess points can also be optimised once you understand it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var points = [CGPoint]()

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        addTouch(touches.first)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        addTouch(touches.first)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        points.removeAll()
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        points.removeAll()
    }

    func addTouch(touch: UITouch?) {
        guard let touch = touch else { return }

        let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        points.append(currentPoint)

        // if you want a limit on your line length, you need these lines
        // 20 is an arbitrary number
        while (points.count > 20) {
            points.removeFirst()
        }
    }
}
```

All that remains is for you to add that to your current line drawing code, and you should be good to go.

Apple have done a number of good WWDC talks on graphics performance. [This one in particular might be helpful.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-506/)

Comment: Thanks for replying @TwoStraws. Would you be able to provide code showing how to save an array of points, how they can be edited and the path recreated?

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation @TwoStraws. I will give it a go and watch the talk as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll want to reset the
path in the `touchesBegan()` method

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    path.removeAllPoints()

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Martin R. I am aware of `removeAllPoints`, but that removes every single point. I want to retain the most recent points and delete all others, I guess a partial removal of points.

Answer (score 1):

You could save an array of points and rebuild your bezier path each time as TwoStraws recommends.

Another option would be to draw your curve using a CAShapeLayer, and change the shapeBegin property. (As you move from shapeBegin = 1.0 to shapeBegin = 0.0 it truncates the beginning of the shape.)

A third option would be to edit the path to delete the earlier points. Erica Sadun has sample code in her outstanding iOS Developers' Cookbook series that shows how to parse the points inside a Bezier path (If I remember correctly it actually uses the underlying CGPath object that is inside a Bezier path.) That would be much faster than rebuilding your bezier path each time, but more work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Duncan C. Would you be able to provide code showing how to save an array of points or editing and deleting points in a bezier path? CAShapeLayer sounds like an interesting approach also, but I'm not sure if it would be suitable here as the path is being created on the go by the user drawing on screen?

Comment: I don't have the references or code  handy (I'm onsite at a client's, and they are at my office.) CAShapeLayer should be fine for drawing on the fly. It's faster/cleaner than overriding drawRect and drawing the curve yourself.